# Cannot use DependencyObject from other thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, drawing

This error appear only when I add these lines to my OnRender override method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Width; i++)
{
    dc.DrawImage(Gouttes[i].Bitmap, new Rect(i, Gouttes[i].Y, 1, Gouttes[i].Length));
}
```

and Visual Studio says me it comes from

```
new Application().Run(new MainWindow());
```

which work either...

Please help me: **what cause that error and how to fix it** ?

Thanks a lot to all that will help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DependencyObject` is a subclass of `DispatcherObject`; these objects are tied to the thread that created them. You can't access their dependency properties directly from another thread. If you need a worker thread to access a dependency property of a `DispatcherObject`, you need to use [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to invoke the action on the dispatcher thread.

Comment: Even with __App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
     {
      MainWindow Mw = new MainWindow();
      Mw.Show();
     }));__, it still throw the same error :(

Comment: @iKiWiXz, it's not the window creation that must be done with Dispatcher, but whatever action you're doing in another thread (just the parts that actually access UI elements)

Comment: Can't lead it to work so I finally found an other way: use a buffer bitmap. This is a strange issue imo btw